# android studio not found device

Tags: android-studio, adb

My device is ASUS K00z.

I connect it's to my PC for develop android app but in android studio not found device.

I set debugging mode to on.

In device manager show yellow exclamation of "Android" under "Other devices" root.

How to solve it's

PS. I use win7 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading the drivers from [ASUS](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx). I didn't find any 'k00z' on there, but it sounds like it may be the Fonepad 7 - they'll likely have different model numbers, so you'll need to know the specifics of your device and download the appropriate driver.

Comment: Thank you very much. I install driver for ASUS Fonepad 7 and then problem is solved.